# Dynamically put data into select option droplist (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, drop-down-menu

Here is the code:
This is were I take data from XML (this works, already tested it without jQuery):

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var select = $('#mySelect');

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://mobile.qmschrysant.nl/keuzemenu/keuzemenu.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('menuitem').each(function(){
                    var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                    select.append("<option/><option class='ddheader'>"+title+"</option>");
                        $(this).find('value').each(function(){
                        var value = $(this).text();
                        select.append("<option class='ddindent' value='"+ value +"'>"+value+"</option>");

                        });
                    });
                    select.children(":first").text("please make a selection").attr("selected",true);
                    select.trigger('updatelayout');
                }
            });
        });
     </script>
```

An this is my select option (HTML):

```
<label for="selectmenu" class="select">Kies planning:</label>
          <form>
            <select id="mySelect" >

                <option>loading</option>
            </select>
          </form>
```

Now the weird thing, when I include this jQuery script:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
```

Then the droplist got awesome look, but does not contain any information.
When I comment out that line, the droplist looks normal, but now it DOES contain the information (so this is the prove, that it does work).

But why doesn't it work when I include the jQuery line? I can't find the problem.

(see picture for maybe better explanation)
[image]

EDIT:
all includes that I use:

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @dystroy I use IE, Opera(my main browser) and Firefox, don't have chrome on the computer. But firefox got also options for console (opera too) I will look.

Comment: Good. Sorry I removed my comment in which I was asking you to check for cross-domain issues and look in the Chrome Developer tool network tab to see whether the xml file was well received.

Comment: @dystroy I looked in Firefox's console, and yes, he finds the XML file

Comment: When I try your code, I get a cross domain error. Your code can only work if mobile.qmschrysant.nl accepts cross domain request or if the html page comes from the same domain.

Comment: @dystroy It shouldn't be (I don't get the crossDomain error, be aware this isn't the wole code btw), the html and the xml file are both in the same dir. And it does work perfectly without that jQuery line.  
Going to install chrome too now

Comment: I tested your code : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/RwgxF/ That's correct, the problem isn't in what we can see. Maybe in your UI configuration or import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP "used the newest jquery mobile.js and now everything works perfectly".

This seemed to be a compatibility problem.

Changed:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

to:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have twice the import of jquery :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Remove the oldest one (the second line).

Or, better, replace both lines by :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(before the inclusion of jquery mobile)

So :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I tried your last answer, but it didn't work, however, when I replace
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` with  
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` it does work (only with the normal looking droplist layout)

So maybe kind of a bug with the new jQuery?

Comment: I know it works without UI : [I tried it in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/RwgxF) . I just hardcoded the XML file to avoid cross domain issues.

Comment: Found it, well.. kinda, I used the newest jquery mobile.js and now everything works perfectly, probably the outdated one contained a bug or something. but thanks for all your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135619/is-it-correct-to-edit-question-to-remove-verbose-introduction#comment378451_135619)

Comment: The introduction? I use it most of the time, to introduce problem, else I got the idea I say/ask something like this: here is my code, go and fix it, so in short, it looks more friendly, but I don't mind if you delete/change it, go ahead :).

Comment: No, do nothing, your question is perfectly valid. I'll just edit to remove the first paragraph :)

Comment: I made a community answer (no rep point for me) from your comment. Don't hesitate to enrich it.

Answer (score 0):

It makes not sense for me :(

The first script needs jQuery to work, so you HAVE jQuery included.

And the

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
```

line doesn't change droplist look.

Comment: I saw it as the reason why the ajax query wasn't made. But maybe there is 2 jquery inclusions and an incompatibility.

Comment: I edit the question a little bit, below you can see what I include.
The code keeps working probably because I also include the jquery/mobile (it is website specially made for mobile use).